# Should I use CTE, Subquery, Temp Table, or a different method?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been working with SQL for a few months and I'm having trouble determining a couple of things for this specific task:

1. Can SQL output the data the way I need it?
2. Which method should I use to make it happen if so?

The table I have has each school broken down by grade level, and the second column has the total enrollment per grade level. I'm trying to sum all enrolled students per grade level for all schools with the following desired output:

```
Grade Total Enrolled
K       7,871
1       8,321
2       8,087
3       8,164
4       8,237
5       8,055
```

Thank you for your help!

I tried this using subqueries, but it showed the totals repeating down each row for all records in the table, instead of just one row of totals.

Subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data']
  WHERE Grade LIKE '%6%'    AND Level = 'MS' ) AS Grade6
```

CTE Code:

```
WITH 
  TK AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Kindergarten FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%KIND%' AND Level = 'ES' )
, T1 AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Grade1       FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%1%'    AND Level = 'ES' )
, T2 AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Grade2       FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%2%'    AND Level = 'ES' )
, T3 AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Grade3       FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%3%'    AND Level = 'ES' )
, T4 AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Grade4       FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%4%'    AND Level = 'ES' )
, T5 AS (  SELECT SUM(Totalenrollment) AS Grade5       FROM Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data'] WHERE Grade LIKE '%5%'    AND Level = 'ES' )   

SELECT * FROM TK 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM T3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T4 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a CASE statement to determine the grade level and then group by the grade level:

```
select 
    case 
        when Grade LIKE '%KIND%' AND Level = 'ES' then 'K'
        when Grade LIKE '%1%'    AND Level = 'ES'  then '1'
        else 'Other Grades' 
    end as GradeLevel,
    sum(TotalEnrollment) as Enrolled
from
    Dbo.['2013Cycle_1_Data']
 group by
    case 
      when Grade LIKE '%KIND%' AND Level = 'ES' then 'K'
      when Grade LIKE '%1%'    AND Level = 'ES'  then '1'
      else 'Other Grades'   
    end
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you @Kyle.  This is a much more simple and logical approach.  I appreciate your help!